# How to echo the server response in android with Http method

Tags: android, http-post

I am calling the JSONParser class with the

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(urlServer, "GET", params);
```

The JSONParser is this

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            if (method == "GET") {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.e("Pasa x aki","ssss");
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object

        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

My error is in "JSON Parser" because the `json object` is `null`. I would like to know what is happening in the `server`. How can I print the echo from the `server`?

Comment: The echo of the server is in String json.

Comment: Off-topic: AFAIK HttpClient is already deprecated for current Android.

Comment: `// return JSON String`. No. That is the json object.

Comment: @greenapps The echo is not in the String json, because the StringBuilder is null, and when I try to convert .toString I get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
           String retSrc = EntityUtils.toString(entity); 
          Log.v("response server ", retSrc);
        }
```

Comment: I would like to do it, but I need 15 of reputation, which I don't have. Sorry